# Sitecore branch template for multilingual website

Tags: multilingual, sitecore8, sitecore-branch-templates

I have a branch template which is shared between several websites in different languages.

The branch template itself has a version for each supported language.

One of those website though has two languages; when I create a subtree with the branch template I would like to create both versions or having a way to create them in two steps.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with `item:added` event handler which adds required language versions. The handler filters items by template ID so that only specific templates are chased:

```
public class MultilingualItemEventHandler
{
    public Guid TemplateId { get; set; }

    public string IgnoredLanguages { get; set; }

    public void OnItemAdded(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        if (args == null || !(Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) is Item item))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (item.TemplateID.Guid != TemplateId)
        {
            return;
        }

        var ignoredLanguages = new ListString(IgnoredLanguages?.ToLowerInvariant() ?? "");
        foreach (var language in item.Languages)
        {
            if (ignoredLanguages.Contains(language.Name.ToLowerInvariant()))
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (language == item.OriginalLanguage)
            {
                continue;
            }

            var descendants = item.Axes.GetDescendants();
            foreach (var descendant in descendants)
            {
                var descendantInLang = descendant.Database.GetItem(descendant.ID, language);
                if (descendantInLang.Versions.Count == 0)
                {
                    descendantInLang.Versions.AddVersion();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The registration in config. Please note how it ignores `en` and `fr-FR` langiages (in case no versions are needed for these languages):

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <events>
            <event name="item:added">
                <handler type="MyProj.MultilingualItemEventHandler, MyProj" method="OnItemAdded">
                    <TemplateId>{some-guid}</TemplateId>
                    <IgnoredLanguages>en|fr-FR</IgnoredLanguages>
                </handler>
            </event>
        </events>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```